# Swift Package Manager add only selected library

Tags: swift, xcode, github, package, swift-package-manager

```
// swift-tools-version:5.5
import PackageDescription
    
let package = Package(
    name: "PKG",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v15)],
    products: [
        .library(name: "Lib1", targets: ["Lib1"]),
        .library(name: "Lib2", targets: ["Lib2"]),
        .library(name: "Lib3", targets: ["Lib3"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "Lib1", dependencies: []),
        .target(name: "Lib2", dependencies: []),
        .target(name: "Lib3", dependencies: []),
    ]
)
```

I'm creating a package with multiple products, I uploaded it to github to use it in SPM in my project,

It's letting me select the libraries I want to add to my project which is what I want, but no matter what I select it bring all the libraries and it's files to my project is this how it works? or can I make it download only the selected libraries and it's dependencies only?

thank you

Comment: SPM operates with packages, ie. package is a unit. If you want smaller part, break big package on smaller and use only one which needed, in other places join them by package dependencies, if needed.

Comment: @Asperi yes I found out about that in swift forums recently but I can't understand why SPM letting me choose what product I want if it is going to load them all anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, SPM will always download the complete repository containing the package/sub-package. You can try out that behaviour at any major library with several products, such as [firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk) (also note that supporting code such as demo applications and tests will be included in the download as well).

For more information, please see [this discussion at swift.org](https://forums.swift.org/t/download-only-selected-libraries-is-that-possible/57062).

The **workaround** is to split your library into several repositories or use another dependency manager, such as [cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html) which fully supports that feature.